# How to portfolio weight constraints for optim function in R? e.g. market neutral portfolio where total weights = 0

Tags: r

Optim allows constraints for upper and lower bounds e.g.
    optim(initialWeights, utilityFn, gr = NULL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0, upper = 1)

**How do you set group constraints? e.g.**

total weights = 1 (a long only portfolio)   OR 
total weights = 0 (a market neutral portfolio)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without data and function is difficult to help. Anyway have you tried `constrOptim`?

Comment: The context of your question appears to be portfolio optimization.  If so you might take a look at the PortfolioAnalytics package on CRAN.  This will calculate optimized portfolio weights using long-only, market neutral, and a number of additional constraints.